# How can I add rounded borders around an image?

Tags: html, css, border, psd

[image: how can I make this type of border]

Hi, I am new to web design and I am struggling on how to make this type of border. If anybody could suggest a solution it'll be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried googling the terms "multiple borders" or "gradient border?" I did, and I came up with several solutions right away. The Internet is the greatest research tool in the history of humanity. Don't cheat yourself by not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the first answer.

> There is a much more simple way to do this using `pseudo-elements`

. The advantage is that you only require one `class` for the whole layout. Pretty simple.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}

.circle{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f4c741;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.circle:before, .circle:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  
}
.circle:before{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 15px solid #f4d041;
}
.circle:after{
  border: 20px solid #f4e242;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am stuck with this border.I don't understand how can i make this
>   type of border.If anybody suggest me it'll helps me a lot.

Something like below should create the rounded corners, however, it's up to you to insert the appropriate images and change the colour if you deem it necessary.

I have used the `CSS3` [`border-radius`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp) property, to provide the `div` elements "rounded corners".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#rcorners1 {
    border-radius: 150px;
    background: #f4e242;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;    
}
#rcorners2 {
    border-radius: 150px;
    background: #f4d041;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;    
}

#rcorners3{
    border-radius: 150px;
    background: #f4c741;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;    
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="rcorners1">
  <div id="rcorners2">
   <div id="rcorners3">
   
   </div>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```